# State Monad with `put` Function

Tags: haskell, state, monads

Looking at the State Monad's [wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad), I'm trying to understand the `runState` and `put` functions.

As I understand `runState`, it takes a first argument of `State`, which has a "universe", `s`, and a value, `a`. It takes a second argument of a universe. Finally, it returns a `(a, s)` where `a` is the new value and `s` is the new universe?

```
ghci> :t runState
runState :: State s a -> s -> (a, s)
```

Example:

```
ghci> let s = return "X" :: State Int String
ghci> runState s 100
("X",100)
```

However, I'm don't understand the `put` result:

```
ghci> runState (put 5) 1
((),5)
```

Since `runState` returns an `(a, s)`, why is the `a` of type `()`?

I'm not confident on my above attempted explanations. Please correct me, and answer my question on `put`.

Comment: "why is the `a` of type `()`?" - Why shouldn't it be?  What were you expecting instead?

Comment: `put` has type `s -> m ()` (see http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Class.html).

Answer (score 6):

When using `put` with the `State` monad, it has the [type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:put) `s -> State s ()`.

`put` sets the state to its argument, and that's all it does. As for its return value: it's essentially a dummy value, because there's nothing useful to return.

This is also evident in its [definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#put) `put s = state $ \ _ -> ((), s)`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to really understand `State`, IMHO, is just to study the code and understand it well enough that you can implement it from memory, like I'm about to do:

```
import Control.Applicative

newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }

instance Functor (State s) where
    fmap f fa = State $ \s -> f (runState fa s)

instance Applicative (State s) where
    pure a = State $ \s -> (a, s)
    ff <*> fa = State $ \ s -> 
        let (f, s') = runState ff s
            (a, s'') = runState fa s'
        in (f a, s'')

instance Monad (State s) where
    return = pure
    ma >>= f = State $ \s -> 
        let (a, s') = runState ma s
            (b, s'') = runState (f a) s'
        in (b, s'')

get :: State s s
get = State $ \s -> (s, s)

put :: s -> State s ()
put s = State $ \_ -> ((), s)

modify :: (s -> s) -> State s ()
modify f = State $ \s -> ((), f s)
```

---

> Since `runState` returns an `(a, s)`, why is the a of type `()`?

That really is just arbitrary/conventional.  Taking the above as a baseline, we could just as well write `modify`, `get` and `put` like this:

```
-- | Replaces the state with the result of applying it to the supplied
-- function.  The result of the action is the original state.
modify :: (s -> s) -> State s s
modify f = State $ \s -> (s, f s)

-- `get` is just what you get when you `modify` with an identity function.
get :: State s s
get = modify (\s -> s)

-- This version of `put` differs from the canonical one because it returns 
-- the old value.
put :: s -> State s s
put s = modify (\_ -> s)
```

In this version `modify` and `put` have the same effects as the original, but additional produce the old state as their result.  Clients that use `modify` and `put` only for the effect would not generally notice the difference.

Alternatively, the "return old state" versions of `modify` and `put` can be written in terms of the official ones.  For example:

```
swap :: s -> State s s
swap s = do
    orig <- get
    put s
    return orig
```

So most of these operations are interdefinable, it doesn't much matter which ones are "basic" and which ones not...

Answer (score 1):

The `runState` function takes an action in the State monad and an initial state and gives you back *both* the result of the calculation and the final state.

A typical use case for `runState` is to hand it a complex action with an intial and to then get the final result and the state back.  In your example, the action is a simple primitive, `put`.

The `put` action takes a new state and produces `()` (pronounced unit) for a value.  It is very similar to how putStrLn has the type `IO ()` It performs an action in the monad, but does not produce a useful value.

So, with `runState (put 5) 1` the initial state, `1` gets blown away by the new state `5`.  The result the state calculation is the result of `put` that is `()`.

Just for kicks, lets look at something just a little more interesting:

```
runState (puts 5 >> return "hello world!") undefined
  --> ("hello world!", 5)
```

Here we have two actions glued together with `>>` (I read this as "then", it is a limited form of bind `>>=` where we just drop the result from the left hand side).  The first action changes the state to `5` the second doesn't touch the state, but results in the string "hello world!" which then becomes the value of the entire calculation.